# How to use correctly AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a JSONobject var (named Acumulator) where i accumulate in it some Json nodes. When time is elapsed I need to send the content of this `JSONObject Accumulator` via http. For this i need to use an AsyncTask.

i do it like this :

```
private class doSynchLocationsTask extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
      //do the job
      if (OK) return true
      else return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
      if (!result) { 
        // here my problem how to access the JSONObject to put it back
        // in the original Acumulator to process it again later ?
      }      
    }

}

JSONObject tmpAccumulator = mAccumulator;
mAccumulator = new JSONObject();  
new doSynchLocationsTask().execute(tmpAccumulator);
```

however i m not sure i do it well. first not sure if this code don't have memory leak or something like this when i do the swap of the tmpAccumulator with mAccumulator, then i don't know how to access in onPostExecute the JSONObject (ie: tmpAccumulator) to put it back in mAccumulator to let the system process them again later

Comment: Couldn't you just create a member variable holding onto a reference to the JSONObject passed into doInBackground that you can just reference from onPostExecute?

Comment: You could do the HTTP and the "JSON accumulation" both in doInBackground. Or you could learn/use RxJava, which seems like a library more suited for this task

Comment: @MichaelKrause hmmmmmmm yes i didn't think to do it like this ! look so simple and i didn't see it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a constructor for your AsyncTask.

Just try something like this:

```
private class doSynchLocationsTask extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Boolean> {
    private JSONObject mJsonObject;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
      mJsonObject = params[0];
      //do the job
      if (OK) return true
      else return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
      if (!result) { 
        // here my problem how to access the JSONObject to put it back
        // in the original Acumulator to process it again later ?

        // Reference mJsonObject here
      }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `doInBackground` would accept different parameters, then a constructor would be needed

Comment: Sure - but it's not really necessary unless it's required.  Why write more code than you need to in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Create constructor for your custom AsyncTask class. Send variables as parameter when creating new object of your AsyncTask class.

```
private class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private String myString;

    public CustomAsyncTask(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //use myString whereever you want in Custom AsyncTask class
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        //use myString whereever you want in Custom AsyncTask class
    }
}
```

call it like this:

```
String myString = "test";

    new CustomAsyncTask(myString).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Comment: No, it sends data to execute method but I send it to constructor but Michael Krause's answer is also the answer.